# RDS Postgres - Free Storage Space (MB) - drastical reduce in space

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

We are using AWS RDS Postgres 9.5.10 with below specs for one of our Databases.

- machine - db.m4.2xlarge
- IOPS -  4000
- Storage -  700 GB.

we usually have around 300 GB of data in this database, but once in a while free storage drops from 400 GB to almost ˜5 GB for no reason. can someone please share possible reasons for this behavior.we have enabled automated backup process to run every night.

Comment: Could be temp files created by queries or (less likely) WAL. temp is usually located in `PGDATA/base/pgsql_tmp`

Comment: `du -sh $PGDATA/base/ | grep G`

Comment: system recovers all 400GB back immediately on rebooting

Comment: also, temp_bytes value in pg_stat_database is too high, is this a concern?